# How to Extract the middle characters from a string without an specific index to start and end it before the space character is read?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column that contains data like:

```
 AB-123 XYZ
 ABCD-456 AAA
 BCD-789 BBB
 ZZZ-963
 Y-85
```

and this is what i need from those string:

```
 123
 456
 789
 963
 85
```

I need the characters from the left after the dash('-') character, then ends before the space character is read.

Thank You guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

http://rextester.com/YTBPQD69134

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ([col] varchar(12));        
INSERT INTO Table1 
    ([col])
VALUES
    ('AB-123 XYZ'),
    ('ABCD-456 AAA'),
    ('BCD-789 BBB');    

select substring
 (col,
  charindex('-',col,1)+1,
  charindex(' ',col,1)-charindex('-',col,1)
  ) from table1;
```

Comment: this works.
but just want to add something, What if the the charater is 'ABC-123'. it doesn't have characters after the number ? 
i tried to run this but it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Original tag on this question was `Oracle` and this answer is based on that tag. Now that, tag is updated to `SqlServer`, this answer is no longer valid, if somebody looking for Oracle solution, this may help.

Use regular expression to arrive at sub string.

```
select trim(substr(regexp_substr('ABCD-456 AAA','-[0-9]+ '),2)) from dual
```

- `'-[0-9]+ '` will grab any string pattern which starts with dash has one or more digits and ends with a `' '` and returns number with dash
- substr will remove `'-'` from above output
- `trim` will remove any trailing `' '`

Comment: thanks for the answer pal, but it doesn't work.
'regexp_substr' is not a recognized built-in function name. I'm using sql server 2008 by the way.

Comment: It is a valid function is `Oracle` which is the database your included in the tag along with `SQL Server`. Why did you put Oracle in the tag?

Comment: i'm a newbie, i thought it was just the same.

Comment: @princevezt, yes its solution for Oracle. I gave you solution based on your initial tag of "Oracle'.I'm no expert in SqlServer. please wait for answers from others

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

Using Substring and PatIndex.

```
         select 
         SUBSTRING(colnm,  PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',colnm), 
        PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',ltrim(RIGHT(colnm,LEN(colnm)-CHARINDEX('-',colnm)))))
         from 
        (
         select 'AB-123 XYZ' colnm union 
         select 'ABCD-456 AAA' union
         select 'BCD-789 BBB' union
         select 'ZX-  23 BBB'

         )a
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume all values has '-' and followed by a space ' '. Below solution will not tolerant to exception case:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUBSTRING(Value, StartingIndex, Length) AS Result
FROM 
    -- You can replace this section of code with your table name
    (VALUES
        ('AB-123 XYZ'),
        ('ABCD-456 AAA'),
        ('BCD-789 BBB')
    ) t(Value)
    -- Use APPLY instead of sub-query is for debugging, 
    -- you can view the actual parameters in the select
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT 
            -- Get the first index of character '-'
            CHARINDEX('-', Value) + 1 AS StartingIndex, 
            -- Get the first index of character ' ', then calculate the length
            CHARINDEX(' ', Value) - CHARINDEX('-', Value) - 1 AS Length
    ) b
```